# Trusty preseed error

Tags: init, preseed, sysv

I have a preseed file that installs Trusty but the install is giving me this error:

```
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: Setting up sysv-rc (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: info: Reordering boot system, log to        
/var/lib/insserv/run-20140722T1052.log
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: error: Something failed while migrating.
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: error: Unable to migrate to dependency based boot     
sequencing.
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: See  
http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot for
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: more information about dependency based boot  
sequencing. To
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: reattempt the migration process run 'dpkg --
configure sysv-rc'.
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: dpkg: error processing package sysv-rc (-- 
configure):
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target:  subprocess installed post-installation script  
returned error exit status 1
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: Errors were encountered while processing:
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target:  sysv-rc
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: E
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: : 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code 
(1)
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: Setting up sysv-rc (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
Jul 22 17:52:42 main-menu[219]: WARNING **: Configuring 'pkgsel' failed with  
error code 100
Jul 22 17:52:42 main-menu[219]: WARNING **: Menu item 'pkgsel' failed.
Jul 22 17:52:56 main-menu[219]: INFO: Modifying debconf priority limit from    
'high' to 'medium'
Jul 22 17:52:56 debconf: Setting debconf/priority to medium
Jul 22 17:52:59 main-menu[219]: INFO: Menu item 'save-logs' selected
```

Seems to me that 'something failed' is very vague. Does anyone have any idea what could have happened? I tried going into a shell and doing the `dpkg --configure sysv-rc` but dpkg isn't installed at that point I guess. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the preseed file as well? Clear out sensitive data like passwords and post to http://paste.ubuntu.com, then add a link in the question.

Comment: @muru looking at the logs here: `/var/lib/insserv/run-20140722T1052.log` it seems that insserv is not in the PATH and thus cannot be run by sysv-rc. Is there a way to define the PATH in the preseed to include the directory where `insserv` lives?